# Unable to initialize static vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to initialize a vector `Stack` inside a class as following.
That vector will be initialized only once and will not be updated ever.

```
#ifndef X_HPP
#define X_HPP

#include <vector>

class Test
{
   public:
      void gen(double x);
      void PopStack();

   private:
         static std::vector<double> Stack;
};

#endif
```

And the `CPP` file is as follows:

```
#include "X.hpp"

int main() {
    std::vector<double> Test::Stack = {1,2,3};
    //{1,2,3} is for representation. In the code, it is generated on the fly and is not a constant seq.
    Test t;
}
```

Compiled using the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 Y.cpp
```

Reported error:

```
Y.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Y.cpp:4:37: error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘=’ token
     std::vector<double> Test::Stack = {1,2,3};
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should move the line:

```
std::vector<double> Test::Stack = {1,2,3};
```

out of the *main* function:

```
std::vector<double> Test::Stack = {1,2,3};

int main() {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

If the vector is populated dynamically, then you might change it to:

```
std::vector<double> Test::Stack;

int main() {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

and fill *Stack* at runtime somehow.

Comment: Okay, that resolves the error. But can you elaborate as why it works now?

Comment: @SuJK This is how static members needed to be initialized since C++ has existed.  It doesn't matter if it was an `int`, `double`, or  `std::vector<double>`.  Static members are initialized outside of all functions, and specified only once in the entire program.

Comment: @SuJK Basically, you have to provide a definition for all static members (there is some stuff with static constants though). Instead of it, you declare an automatic variable with the name `Test::Stack` inside the `main` function which is obviously not the thing you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot initialize a static member variable within the body of a function (`main`, in your case)

usually, you put that kind of code in one and one only cpp file, outside the body of any method.
something like this:

```
std::vector<double> Test::Stack = {1,2,3};
int main() {
    //{1,2,3} is for representation. In the code, it is generated on the fly and is not a constant seq.
    Test t;
}
```